# How to search array and find item that user input? (in Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a somthing that can search my 2D array of towns and details on the towns using the users input. It should then output the town that is searched for and the details that go with it.

```
townInfo = [['Berwick Upon Tweed', 'Northumberland', '12870', '468'], ['Bideford', 'Devon', '16262', '430'], ['Bognor Regis', 'West Sussex', '62141', '1635'], ['Bridlington', 'East Yorkshire', '33589', '791'], ['Bridport', 'Dorset', '12977', '425'], ['Cleethorpes', 'Lincolnshire', '31853', '558'], ['Colwyn Bay', 'Conway', '30269', '953'], ['Dover', 'Kent', '34087', '861'], ['Falmouth', 'Cornwall', '21635', '543'], ['Great Yarmouth', 'Norfolk', '58032', '1467'], ['Hastings', 'East Sussex', '85828', '1998'], ['Maidstone', 'Kent', '89684', '2173'], ['Morecambe', 'Lancashire', '49569', '1302'], ['Scarborough', 'North Yorkshire', '38364', '772'], ['Skegness', 'Lincolnshire', '16806', '512'], ['Torquay', 'Devon', '62968', '1568'], ['Whitby', 'N Yorkshire', '13594', '321']]

whattown = input("which town would you like to see").title()

x=0

for i in range(len(townInfo)):
  for j in range(len(townInfo[i])):
    if townInfo[i][j]==whattown:
      print("Found it!")
      x=1
      break
    else:
      x=x+1
      if x==j*i:
        print("not found")
```

I have included x because it was printing not found for every item that wasnt my input instead of just once. the if x==j*i line should make it only print not found if all of the items were not found and x is equal to j*i (which I think is the total number of items in my array). I was just trying to get it to search and output before I get it to output from the table
I have probably not gone with the best method so if you can think of a better one please tell me.

Comment: What are the meanings of the elements in the list? Is the idea that a user can search even by the number in the list?

Comment: You can use Dictionary to save the information, name of town would be the key. Searching would be much easier.

Comment: the numbers are population and area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of the code you're looking for.

```py
all_town_info = [['Berwick Upon Tweed', 'Northumberland', '12870', '468'], ['Bideford', 'Devon', '16262', '430'], ['Bognor Regis', 'West Sussex', '62141', '1635'], ['Bridlington', 'East Yorkshire', '33589', '791'], ['Bridport', 'Dorset', '12977', '425'], ['Cleethorpes', 'Lincolnshire', '31853', '558'], ['Colwyn Bay', 'Conway', '30269', '953'], ['Dover', 'Kent', '34087', '861'], ['Falmouth', 'Cornwall', '21635', '543'], ['Great Yarmouth', 'Norfolk', '58032', '1467'], ['Hastings', 'East Sussex', '85828', '1998'], ['Maidstone', 'Kent', '89684', '2173'], ['Morecambe', 'Lancashire', '49569', '1302'], ['Scarborough', 'North Yorkshire', '38364', '772'], ['Skegness', 'Lincolnshire', '16806', '512'], ['Torquay', 'Devon', '62968', '1568'], ['Whitby', 'N Yorkshire', '13594', '321']]

what_town = input("which town would you like to see? ").title()

found_at_least_one = False
for town_info in all_town_info:
  for town_info_element in town_info:
    if town_info_element == what_town:
      print("Found it!")
      found_at_least_one = True

if not found_at_least_one:
  print("not found")
```

I'll just go through the changes made in order to fix the code:

- In Python we usually use snake_case for variable naming
- Another thing that is nice about Python is that to iterate over a list we don't need to use indexes. We can just say `for town_info in all_town_info` which will put each element of the list into `town_info` variable where we can use it. The same goes for `town_info_element`
- In the end, to see if an element has been found it is easiest to use a flag. First we say that we haven't found a single town, and then if we do find one, we just declare the variable to be `True`. Later we check if any element has been found, and print the message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be simplified by using dictionary as follows:

```
townInfo = {'Berwick Upon Tweed' : ['Northumberland', '12870', '468'], 
            'Bideford' : ['Devon', '16262', '430'], 
            'Bognor Regis' : ['West Sussex', '62141', '1635'], 
            'Falmouth': ['Cornwall', '21635', '543'], 
            }
whattown = raw_input("which town would you like to see")
if whattown in townInfo:
    print(whattown , townInfo[whattown])
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0):

**As you said you want to output the information of each town:**

this will find the town and output all of its information.

```
townInfo = [['Berwick Upon Tweed', 'Northumberland', '12870', '468'], ['Bideford', 'Devon', '16262', '430'], ['Bognor Regis', 'West Sussex', '62141', '1635'], ['Bridlington', 'East Yorkshire', '33589', '791'], ['Bridport', 'Dorset', '12977', '425'], ['Cleethorpes', 'Lincolnshire', '31853', '558'], ['Colwyn Bay', 'Conway', '30269', '953'], ['Dover', 'Kent', '34087', '861'], ['Falmouth', 'Cornwall', '21635', '543'], ['Great Yarmouth', 'Norfolk', '58032', '1467'], ['Hastings', 'East Sussex', '85828', '1998'], ['Maidstone', 'Kent', '89684', '2173'], ['Morecambe', 'Lancashire', '49569', '1302'], ['Scarborough', 'North Yorkshire', '38364', '772'], ['Skegness', 'Lincolnshire', '16806', '512'], ['Torquay', 'Devon', '62968', '1568'], ['Whitby', 'N Yorkshire', '13594', '321']]

whattown = input("Which town would you like to see?\n").title()

found = False

for town in townInfo:
    for townElement in town:
        if townElement == whattown:
            print("Found it!\n")
            for each in town:
                print(each + "\n")
            found = True
if not found:
    print("Not found!\n")
```